# Context-Free Grammar Question

Tags: computability, context-free, computation-models

Given a regular Expression: 0^a 1^b 0^c, where a+b=c and a,b,c >= 0.
Find the cfg for this expression.

Here is what I tried to do:

s -> AsB

A -> 01

B -> 0

But then a language could be 010100 which does is not apart of the expression.
I tried other ways but then I was not able to fulfill the a+b=c rule.


e = epsilon


Using the Hint Below:

S -> 0S0 | A

A -> 1A0 | e

Comment: Hint: $0^a 1^b 0^c = 0^a (1^b 0^b) 0^a$.

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/self-learner).